# Why super class protected variable is inaccessible from sub class?

Tags: java, inheritance, protected

I am trying to understand why the protected variable in superclass is inaccessible in child class?

```
package pack1;

public class Parent {

    protected int r;

    public int s;
}



package pack2;

import pack1.Parent;

public class Child extends Parent {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Parent obj = new Child();
        obj.r = 2;      //r is not accessible here. It becomes accessible when I make it static.
        obj.s = 3;      //s is accessible.
    }
}
```

Comment: main is a static method, not an object method. You will be able access 'r' directly from any non-static code in Child.

Comment: This is called Invariance and Covariance. If you Google it, you’ll find tutorials that can explain it much better than we can in an answer here. please refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/215497/in-java-difference-between-package-private-public-protected-and-private) to understand difference between `public`, `protected` and `private`

Comment: @TomDrake Thanks for the answer! So I created an instance of Parent i.e. obj...my query is why is public variable "s" is accessible but protected variable "r" is not?

Comment: here you are using parent class instance which is base class so in different package it is not accessible.. use Child class instead of parent

Comment: @vinay chhabra Thanks Vinay!

Comment: A method in subclass can access protected member in superclass via a subclass instance only. I refer you to JLS 6.6.2, 6.6.2.1 and 6.6.2.2

Comment: @nabsATX Thanks!

Comment: Why a protected member of a superclass can't be accessed from a subclass by using a superclass' reference?
http://www.xyzws.com/Javafaq/why-a-protected-member-of-a-superclass-cant-be-accessed-from-a-subclass-by-using-a-superclass-reference/109